# Relação 2 tabelas contas a pagar e a receber - Só aparece a soma de contas a pagar se recebido

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, relacionamento

Estou com uma certa dificuldade em obter um resultado esperado via SQL.
Talvez o mesmo, só possa ser solucionado via linguagem de programação, mas resolvi postar na expectativa de que alguém possa me ajudar em uma falta de conhecimento da minha parte.

Eu tenho uma pagina de contas a receber e outra de contas a pagar.
Na pagina de contas a pagar, só pode aparecer na tela os registros de contas a pagar, caso a conta referente esteja como recebida na tabela de contas a receber, ou seja, não quero que aparece todos os registros de contas a pagar, pelo menos nesta pagina especifica.

Criei a seguinte SQL e o resultado é o esperado:

```
SELECT p.valor, p.id_imovel, p.data_vencimento
FROM contas_a_pagar AS p 
INNER JOIN contas_a_receber AS r ON r.data_vencimento=p.data_vencimento 
WHERE r.recebido=1
```

Porem gostaria de deixar este resultado mais enxuto, trazendo os valores de contas a pagar somados e com o valor de aluguel recebido, pois a intenção e subtrair os valores e mostrar o que sobrou(receita)

```
SELECT SUM(p.valor) AS despesas, r.valor AS valor_aluguel, p.id_imovel, p.data_vencimento 
FROM contas_a_pagar AS p 
INNER JOIN contas_a_receber AS r ON r.data_vencimento=p.data_vencimento 
WHERE r.recebido=1 
GROUP BY p.id_imovel
```

Estou usando o phpmyadmin para fazer os testes acima e o mesmo não causou nenhum erro, porem usando um editor/console online houve um erro ao utilizar a função SUM()

Mas blz, até ai tranquilo.

O problema é que o valor de aluguel que deveria ser de **4.000** no **id_imovel=2** esta como **3.000**.
Os valores de despesas estão corretos **1.500 para o id_imovel=1** e **1.700 para o id_imovel=2** o problema esta no valor de aluguel que esta errado.
O mesmo seria utilizado para fazer um calculo de subtrair EX: 1.500 - 4000 = 2.500

Imagem do resultado via phpmyadmin
https://postimg.cc/vc18xKqn

Paiza - Mysql Online
https://paiza.io/projects/hO4XodwbhL5xoN34BkteLg?language=mysql

Comment: não pode trazer um resultado "agregado" (`sum`) e outro não agragado, ou traz tudo com soma, media, etc ou o resultado não bate.
Imagina que na sua tabela tem 10 valores 1 a 10 por exemplo, e faz um `select sum(valor), valor from ... where ... group by campo` como o banco pode trazer hora uma soma agrupada por um campo, hora os valores separados?  isso gera confusão. Se tem `SUM(p.valor)` também deveria ter `SUM(r.valor)`, e a data assim como o id_imovel deveria estar no group by

Comment: Levei um tempinho para entender este 0 de despesa e receita, e o pq de fazer um union em uma subconsulta. Seu comentário foi perfeito, obrigado pela ajuda em me fazer enxergar o pq do problema, fico agradecido.

Comment: Você ainda pode melhorar gerando uma sequencia artificsl de datas com valores zerados para os casos de dias sem a duplak ocorrência.

Comment: Entendi. O mesmo esquema do zero de valores, porém para as datas. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--tente algo assim

```
select sum(despesas) despesas, sum(receitas) receitas,id_imovel,data_vencimento
from
(
SELECT SUM(p.valor) AS despesas, 0 receitas,p.id_imovel, p.data_vencimento 
FROM contas_a_pagar AS p 
union all
SELECT 0 despsas ,SUM(R.valor) AS receitas, r.id_imovel, r.data_vencimento 
FROM   contas_a_receber AS r ON r.data_vencimento=p.data_vencimento 
WHERE r.recebido=1 
) virtual
GROUP BY virtual.id_imovel,virtual.data_vencimento
```

Comment: Só tive um problema com a palavra virtual, me parece que a mesma é reservada, pela base de dados em alguma outra função, acabei por utilizar teste.